# Converting boolean expression to CNF

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to convert an expression to CNF. I've converted it to DNF and I know its CNF, but i just can't do it by myself.

I've tried the other answers, but with them it bloats to very long expression. It will took several hours just to write down.

$¬A¬B(¬C + D)(C + ¬D) + (A + B)(C¬D + ¬CD) $

This is DNF:

$¬A¬B¬C¬D + ¬A¬BCD + AC¬D + A¬CD + BC¬D + B¬CD $

Thank you

Comment: "Bloats to very long expression" ... this is typical, except for specially-chosen problems.  Here, you have only 4 letters, so probably it is feasible to compute the truth table and use that to easily construct the CNF.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to convert such expression is [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=not%20A%20and%20not%20B%20and%20%28not%20C%20or%20D%29%20and%28C%20or%20not%20D%29%20or%20%28A%20or%20B%29%20and%20%28C%20and%20not%20D%20or%20not%20C%20and%20D%29).

[image]